# Removing the Archive text from Internet browser header

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to remove the Archives text from the `<title>` of the page. I am using Wordpress with `WooCommerce` and the `Flatsome` theme but can't seem to find it in the settings anywhere.

Its also showing up on Google as "`archives`".

For example http://www.makemyornament.com/product-category/pets/dogs/

If you look in the web browser it says "Dogs Archive".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using yoast SEO plugin then the easiest method is to remove the archive word. Navigate "titles & metas-> Taxonomies->category"

find:

```
%%term_title%% Archives %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

replace it with:

```
%%term_title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

**OR**

Just place below code in your theme function.php

```
function overwrite_wp_title($title, $sep)
{
  // Look for the string " Archives" (note the leading space), 
  // and strip it out of $title:
  return preg_replace("/ Archives/", "", $title);
}
add_filter("wp_title", "overwrite_wp_title", 11, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a plugin in for that. You can try this one:
["All in One SEO Pack"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/)
Install the plugin and change the archive settings.